# Dynamic creation of fieldname in pandas groupby-aggregate

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, aggregate

I have many aggregations of the type below in my code:

```
period = 'ag'
index = ['PA']
lvl = 'pa'
wm = lambda x: np.average(x, weights=dfdom.loc[x.index, 'pop'])
dfpa = dfdom[(dfdom['stratum_kWh'] !=8)].groupby(index).agg(
    pa_mean_ea_ag_kwh = ('mean_ea_'+period+'_kwh', wm),
    pa_pop = ('dom_pop', 'sum'))
```

It's straightforward to build the right hand side of the aggregation equation. I want to also dynamically build the left hand side of the aggregate equations so that 'dom', 'ea', 'ag' and 'kw/kwh/thm' can be all created as variable inputs and used depending on which process I'm executing. This will significantly reduce the amount of code that needs to be written and updates will also be easier to manage as otherwise I need to write separate otherwise identical code for each combination of the above.

Can I use eval to do this? I'd appreciate guidance on how to do it. Thanks.

Adding code written after feedback from Vaidøtas I.:

```
index = ['PA'] 
lvl = 'pa' 
fname = lvl+"_pop" 

b = f'dfdom.groupby({index}).agg({lvl}_pop = ("dom_pop", "sum"))' 
dfpab = exec(b)
```

The output for the above is a 'NoneType object'. If I lift the text in variable b and directly run the code as show below, I get a dataframe.

```
dfpab = dfdom.groupby(['PA']).agg(pa_pop = ("dom_pop", "sum"))
```

(I've simplified my original example to better connect with the second code added.)

Answer (score 1):

Use exec(), eval() is something different

For example:

```
exec(f"variable_name{added_namepart} = variable_value{added_valuepart}")
```

Comment: Will exec work if this code is within a function? I've used it in the past and had to restructure my entire code because it stopped working when I moved my code to within a function (called by another function)

Comment: I tried it outside the function: ```exec(dfpa = dfdom.groupby(index).agg('pa_' + 'pop' = ('"dom_pop"', '"sum"')))```. Got the same error had I not used exec: **SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression**

Comment: It works, you're just doing it wrong. The argument inside exec must be a string. I will modify my answer shortly to give you an idea. Let me know if you got it.

Comment: ofcourse! thanks for providing an example. My code runs but the output isn't a dataframe. When I run the following my output is a NoneType object:

```index = ['PA'] lvl = 'pa' fname = lvl+"_pop" b = f'dfdom.groupby({index}).agg({lvl}_pop = ("dom_pop", "sum"))' dfpab = exec(b)
```

if I lift the text in variable b and directly run the code as show below, I get a dataframe. 
```dfpab = dfdom.groupby(['PA']).agg(pa_pop = ("dom_pop", "sum"))```

Comment: have added the above in my original question so it's more readable.

Comment: no it provides a NoneType object.  Though without the exec the code works fine

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223656/discussion-between-smodi-and-vaidotas-i).